# To make bluetooth connection pc between device through web app, pc side program, what is it made from?

Tags: server, web-applications, bluetooth, tizen

I almost understand how to send message device to device.

But, I don't know how to do this with pc.

I tried to find it, but the most curious thing is,

'How can I make server side program on pc?'

I know how to provide web service by server, but for that, I have to make environment like APM on PC.

But, that's not what I want. Because it means, someone who want to use that program should make environment like that I have.

Actually, I tried to make remote controller application like X-remote...

That kind of applications, just download program and install it on pc, then pc act as a server.

what is it made from? C#? php? Java swing?? I have no idea about that...

Device is Tizen, so we will make a web app.

How can I make pc program like other remote application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that right now you cannot emulate Bluetooth on Emulator. As far as I remember when developing some sample applications, we have been using some fixed data. You could also write whole application using simple PHP server, and change the communication from HTTP to Bluetooth at the end of development. 
Please analyze BluetootchChat sample application in the SDK, it should give you an overview about the BT communication in JavaScript.
Remember about the privileges in config.xml file.